# Google Chrome Console RegExp weird behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Here's my code in Chrome console:

`var re = new RegExp('^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example.com','g');`

And then I test:

`re.test('example.com');`

Results I get are weird.. After testing RegExp two times I get true and false after. Continuing testing same string I get rotation of true and false. While the first result is correct and it  returns true , why the second returns false?

Comment: You need to reset your lastIndex probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: Unfortunately resetting last index works only in Firefox. But it suggested me not to use global flag.. and it worked!..

Comment: `re.lastIndex = 0` should work across the board. Does for me in Chrome - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

Comment: Btw I thought it's a Chrome bug, not Javascript issue at all. The question can be closed. Thx!

Comment: FYI `/` is not a special regex character, unless you use it a delimiter.